# What are the causes of these marks on a ceiling?

Tags: ceiling

Every number of years we get these marks on our ceiling - where they get progressively worse.
It is a dusty substance, but even a vacuum and wash don’t work longer term which results in a repaint.
Any thoughts as to what causes this? Seems the [very fine] dust is attracted to specific locations.

[image]
[image]

Room is heated by central air. Vents are not near or relative to the marks.

Comment: How do you heat your home?

Comment: Usually a slight difference of moisture at the ceiling joists and the spaces between them.  Dust and dirt tend to collect there, but would not be surprized if you mention there was a heat outlet below that section.

Comment: Check out https://inspectapedia.com/interiors/Thermal_Tracking.php. It looks like it could be spots where rolls of ceiling insulation meet.

Comment: I’m betting the insulation batts are short of the exterior wall

Comment: @Kris It's interesting that it is in every other bay. I wonder if the other end of the ceiling has opposite bays with the same issue.

Comment: @MonkeyZeus  some one may have thought this was a good idea to increase air flow into attic.

Comment: Is there attic space above? Or is this between floors?

Comment: Usually the marks line up with ceiling joists, your marks seem to be more spread out near the walls.  If possible to go above there safely, might want to add more insulation.  Joists will be colder than where insulation is.

Comment: @crip659 Looks like a vaulted ceiling so I would bet that access is limited or non-existent.

Comment: I would bet soffit vents and possibly less insulation could cause condensation, condensation in a warm moist area a mold spore would grow. looking outside if the vents line up. I know there are anti fowling paints approved for outside use but not sure if ok for inside use. Cleaning with a +3% solution of hydrogen peroxide may kill it and bleach it out. Apply with a roller if it doesn’t work the roller will still work for paint.

Answer (score 2):

My first thought is "ghosting".  This is mainly seen in poorly insulated areas and often follows studs and joists (may even see it on the drywall nails or screws).  The ghosting is caused by sections of the wall or ceiling being cooler than the rest of the wall and cool enough to get *some* condensation.  Every house has some amount of dust floating around, and this dust sticks to the wet parts of your walls/ceilings better than it does to the dry parts and builds up.  Over time this becomes noticeable.  This is particularly bad when you have anything burning in your house (fireplace, kerosene heater, someone is a bad cook, etc.) or if you keep your windows open (more dust).  As mentioned in the comments, this is really bad around areas that get a lot of air flow a (registers, returns, etc.).

The solution is to first fix the insulation problem, clean the walls, then repaint.

That said, your second picture looks more like water damage, potentially, than ghosting.  It's hard to tell, but I can almost see where water has pooled in areas and began dripping down the wall.  However, it's hard to tell from the lighting in the picture.

Answer (score 0):

Moisture from above is my first guess. Causes can vary - Poor vapor sealing / damaged vapor barrier, urine from rodents nesting (yeah, I've lived in one of those, and the landlord was useless - squirrels in the attic insulation - you'd hear the scratching) &/or ice dams causing roof leaks (or just plain old roof leaks.)

Comment: You don't think some of this is ghosting?  I agree some of it looks like water damage, but the OP mentioned black dust as well.

Comment: Black dust could be mold/mildew forming due to dampness.For that matter, if there's soot/dust around, it won't care if the dampness is from above or below. Based on *my* experience and trying to analyze the problem from a couple of pictures, I see what appears to be water damage. In my experience, a little water damage below has usually meant a great deal more above, So my gut reaction is not "some condensation forming below" but there's no guarantee that my gut is more right than yours.

Comment: Well, better to check for water than assume it's not.  Oh, and *my* gut hasn't been calibrated for a long time...so it might be out of spec. ;)